# C++ MFC How to prevent duplicate values in each Ch?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have the following code:
And I would like to select one Ch without the number which has been selected in the other Ch.
For example, in Ch5, "1","2","3","37" can not be selected.

```
BOOL CMaintenanceHeadDispenserDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
CMaintenanceChildDlg::OnInitDialog();

CRect rc(0, 0, 0, 0);
m_edtDist.Create( NULL, NULL, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_DISABLED, rc, this, IDC_EDT_MT_HEAD_DISPENSER_DIST );
m_edtDist.SetInputMode( 1 );
m_edtDist.SetInputRange( 999.999, 0.0 );
m_edtDist.EnableRightInputMode( TRUE, 2 );

m_edtOutput.Create(NULL, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_DISABLED, rc, this, IDC_EDT_MT_HEAD_DISPENSER_OUTPUT);

CDeviceConfigDispenserController* p = CDeviceConfigDispenserController::GetInstance();  
SDeviceConfigDispenser d;
p->GetData( d );

m_DispenserChInfoSet.GetChMap(m_mapCh);

for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    m_cmbCh[i].ResetContent();
    m_cmbCh[i].SetScrollCnt(5);
    m_cmbCh[i].SetHitTrace( TRUE );

m_edtCh[i].Create(NULL,NULL,WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|WS_DISABLED,rc,this,IDC_EDT_MT_HEAD_DISPENSER_CH1 + i);
    m_edtCh[i].SetLimitTextNum(32);

    int itemCnt = 0;
    CString strCh;
    for( map<int, CString>::iterator it = m_mapCh.begin(); it != m_mapCh.end(); it++ ) {
        strCh.Format(_T("%d"), it->first);

        m_cmbCh[i].InsertString(itemCnt, strCh);
        m_cmbCh[i].SetItemData(itemCnt, it->first);
        if( d.nUseCh[i] == it->first ) {
            m_cmbCh[i].SetCurSel( itemCnt );
            m_edtCh[i].SetString( it->second );
        }
        itemCnt++;
    }

    m_rdoCh[i].SetCheck( BST_UNCHECKED );
}

 afx_msg LRESULT CMaintenanceHeadDispenserDlg::OnCbxSelchanged(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
//int j = 0;    //ou
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    if( m_cmbCh[i].m_hWnd == (HWND)lParam )
    {
        int Cnt = m_cmbCh[i].GetCount();
        if( (int)wParam < Cnt && (int)wParam >= 0) {
            m_cmbCh[i].SetCurSel( (int)wParam );

            int Index = (int)m_cmbCh[i].GetItemData( m_cmbCh[i].GetCurSel() );
            map<int, CString>::iterator it = m_mapCh.find( Index );
            if( it != m_mapCh.end() ) {
                m_edtCh[i].SetString( it->second );
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand the question.

Comment: Have you tried removing the selected number from the other combo boxes once it has been selected?  That would prevent the user from selecting it in the remaining combo box controls.